# GROUP BY is really slow when joining the temporary table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

The table structure is simple:

```
CREATE TABLE `trade` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `all_idx` (`date`,`account`,`amount`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

There are about 5M records in this table.

The requirement is:

- giving a date range
- find the **FIRST MAXIMUM** trade amount of each account in the date range
- find the **MINIMUM** trade amount **AFTER**
- calculate the **DIFFERENCE** between these two amounts (could be 0)

Here is how I wrote the SQLs:

```
-- step 1: find the max amount, took about 0.6s
select account, max(amount) max_amount
from trade
where date between '20160101' and '20161220'
group by account;

-- step 2: find the first date, took about 1s
drop temporary table if exists tmp_max_amount;
create temporary table tmp_max_amount
select t1.account, min(t1.date) date, t1.amount
from trade t1, (
    select account, max(amount) max_amount
    from trade
    where date between '20160101' and '20161220'
    group by account
) t2
where t1.account = t2.account and t1.amount = t2.amount
group by t1.account, t1.amount;

-- step 3: find the min amount, took about 50s
drop temporary table if exists tmp_min_amount;
create temporary table tmp_min_amount
select t1.account, min(t1.amount) min_amount
from trade t1, tmp_max_amount t2
where t1.account = t2.account and t1.date >= t2.date
group by t1.account;

-- step 4: calculate the difference, took about 0.8s
select x.account, (max_amount - min_amount) diff
from tmp_max_amount x, tmp_min_amount n
where x.account = n.account;
```

The SQL in step 3 took about 50 seconds. Is there any way to improve the speed?

Sample data:

```
    id | account | date     | amount
 ------|---------|----------|---------
     1 |    1000 | 20151001 |   1000 <- not in range
     2 |    3000 | 20151002 |    100 <- not in range
     3 |    1000 | 20160105 |    800 <- max of 1000
     4 |    2000 | 20160110 |    200 <- max of 2000
     5 |    2000 | 20160115 |    100 <- min of 2000
     6 |    3000 | 20160201 |   1200
....
 10000 |    2000 | 20161210 |    200 <- no the first max
 10001 |    3000 | 20161210 |    500
 10002 |    3000 | 20161212 |   1500 <- max & min of 3000
 10003 |    1000 | 20161213 |    300 <- min of 1000
```

Expected result:

```
account | diff
--------|------
   1000 |  500 <- (800 - 300)
   2000 |  100 <- (200 - 100)
   3000 |    0 <- (1500 - 1500)
...
```

Comment: perhaps by avoiding the use of temporary tables! Can you post some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: @e4c5 thanks for your reply, I just added the sample data as requested.

Comment: Try adding an index on tmp_max_amount, the same way you would for any other table.  Also, be sure to check your index usage from both the trade table and the temp one using EXPLAIN on your third query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the `JOIN...ON` syntax.

Step 2 needs `INDEX(account, amount)`

Step 3 needs an index that is most easily created in Step 2 by doing

```
create temporary table tmp_max_amount
    ( INDEX(account, date) )   -- This was added
SELECT ..;
```

(This may not be optimal, but it should help.)

Comment: The index on temporary table helps!